# Install iOS app in MacBook Pro 2018 with an Intel chip without using an iphone

Tags: macos, ios

I want to install an iOS app in my MacBook Pro 2018

It has an Intel chip but I don't have an iPhone or iPad. Is there a way to install it using some software?

Answer (score 1):

The 2018 MacBook Pro does not support running iPhone/iPad apps.

You will need a Mac with an Apple Silicon CPU in order to run iOS apps - for example the 2020 13-inch MacBook Pro or the 2021 14- or 16-inch MacBook Pro.

Comment: Okay, I guess there's no way. Thanks for the information

Comment: Yes, you're right - there's no way to do that currently. If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted.